# org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFolderException error navigating through folder using commons vfs 2.0

Tags: apache, vfs

I just started to use apache commons vfs 2.0. I was trying to get file list of folder in `c:\` but got error with `c:\document and setting`. Here is the code:

```
FileSystemManager fsm = VFS.getManager();
    FileObject fo=fsm.resolveFile("c:\\");
    FileObject[] fos=fo.getChildren();
    for(FileObject f:fos){
        FileType ft=f.getType();
        if(f.getType().equals(FileType.FOLDER)){
                for( FileObject fc:f.getChildren()){
                    System.out.println(fc.getName().getPath());
                }
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileNotFolderException: Could not list the contents of "file:///c:/Documents and Settings" because it is not a folder.
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractFileObject.getChildren(AbstractFileObject.java:693)
    at mypack.gui.FileExplorer.<init>(FileExplorer.java:31)
    at mypack.gui.FileExplorer.main(FileExplorer.java:42)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proper protocol to connect via VFS Try this:

```
FileSystemManager fsm = VFS.getManager();
FileObject fo=fsm.resolveFile("file:///c:/");
FileObject[] fos=fo.getChildren();
for(FileObject f:fos){
    FileType ft=f.getType();
    if(f.getType().equals(FileType.FOLDER)){
            for( FileObject fc:f.getChildren()){
                System.out.println(fc.getName().getPath());
            }
    }
}
```